# libpng warning: incorrect bKGD chunk length

Tags: android, compilation, png

I'm compiling my app (it's a theme with a simple background) but I get an error: `"libpng warning: incorrect bKGD chunk length"`.

So when I obtain my compiled apk and I try, it doesn't work.

Here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25.0dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:id="@id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21.0dip"
    android:text="@string/Line3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:id="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="22.0dip"
    android:text="@string/Line2"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/TextView01" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="17.0dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:id="@id/textView1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16.0dip"
    android:text="@string/Line1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" />
```

Comment: Are you sure all of characters of your file name are low case?

Comment: Yes. The file name is "bg.png".. I've changed the real "bg.png" with another image with the same name

Comment: meybe your name file is short.please rename it and clean your project and try again.

Comment: I'll try..  But the old file has the same name and has been working very well before my editing

Comment: If your "bg.png" originally had one colortype and has been rewritten with another colortype, the bKGD chunk data and length should have been adjusted accordingly.
It's likely you aren't using the bKGD data anyhow, if your image is opaque and covers your entire screen, so the simplest solution would be to remove the bKGD chunk. [changing answer to a comment because there is no question actually asked]